# Using a function in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the return value to display but it is only doing the final else procedure.  Something is wrong with my if statements...  I am using an html page to call this php page... When i put in results, regardless of the operation it only displays the multiplication value

```
function total($num1, $num2, $op) {
    if($op == "+"){
        $total = "$num1 + $num2 = ".($num1 + $num2);
        return $total;
    } elseif($_POST['operation'] == "-"){
        $total = "$num1 - $num2 = ".($num1 - $num2);
        return $total;
    } elseif($_POST['operation'] == "/"){
        $total = "$num1 / $num2 = ".($num1 / $num2);
        return $total;
    } else{
        $total = "$num1 * $num2 = ".($num1 * $num2);
        return $total;
    }
}

echo total($num1, $num2, $op);
```

Comment: Give us some actual values to work with

Comment: You start with `$op == '+'` then you just screw the pooch by using `$_POST['operation']` in the rest of your comparisons in your PHP function.

Comment: You're doing `if($op == "+")` then `elseif($_POST['operation'] == "-")` shouldn't that be `if($_POST['operation'] == "+")`? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Really something obviously weird. I guess...

Comment: *...and now,* everyone's waiting on *the verdict*.

Comment: I'd like to see values defined for $num1, $num2 and $op.

Comment: I am in the process of working on it now, but I did use both $op and the other one for all of them, I forgot that I was debugging when I posted the first comment.  Give me a few mins and I will share my thoughts :)

Comment: thanks for the help.  I just needed to organize better and make sure to use the $op for them all.  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because you are mixing $op and $_POST['operation']. Also, you have a concern about your if statements. Because you return in each one, you can simplify this a great deal without increasing runtime complexity.

```
function total($num1, $num2, $op) {
  if($op == "+")
    return "$num1 + $num2 = ".($num1 + $num2);
  if($op == "-")
    return "$num1 - $num2 = ".($num1 - $num2);
  if($op == "/")
    return "$num1 / $num2 = ".($num1 / $num2);
  return "$num1 * $num2 = ".($num1 * $num2);
}
```

Comment: you my sir made my night!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just forgot to use $op, you used $_POST instead .

Try

```
function total($num1, $num2, $op)
{
  if($op == "+"){
    $total = "$num1 + $num2 = ".($num1 + $num2);
    return $total;
  }
  elseif($op == "-"){
    $total = "$num1 - $num2 = ".($num1 - $num2);
    return $total;
  }
  elseif($op == "/"){
    $total = "$num1 / $num2 = ".($num1 / $num2);
    return $total;
  }
  else{
    $total = "$num1 * $num2 = ".($num1 * $num2);
    return $total;
  }
}
echo total($num1, $num2, $op);
```

Comment: `$_POST` *is* a global (actually a superglobal).

Comment: You're either completely right, or completely wrong. Seeing that they're using both variables and POST arrays, well... time will tell. Let's see what the OP has to say, amongst comments under their question ;-)

Comment: thanks guys, replacing the if statements with the $op and using the code below returned the proper values.